# Penthao Dataintegration (PDI) 8.3 CE showing Error "localhost:9051" page not found on all dialogs except browse repository

Tags: localhost, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pdi

I hope you can help me out here. I have a very strange situation and no Idea how to solve it. I installed Penthao Dataintegration (PDI) 8.3 on a Windows Server. I use seperated home folders and a Database Repostiory. It worked just fine but out of nowhere now all GUI-Dialogs (f.ex. Open File, Marketplace, Connect Repostiory, Save new Trafos and Jobs...) show all the same error

"
Page can't be shown check if http://localhost:9051 is correct
"
[error opening marketplace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgr2l.png) 
[error using open file dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odqm2.png)

Even if I delete the PDI Folder and the .kettle, .pentaho folder in my home folder and freshly unzip it, the error persists. The only way I was able to solve it, was to install it on a new server. There it worked for some days and is now broken again. Clearly I am connected to the database repository as it shows me the jobs and trafos there when using the explore repository function.

Does anyone know how to reslove that?

How can I remove everything from pdi 8.3 ce to get a fresh installation? Or which folders does pdi 8.3 create (and where)? It seems it has stored some files somewhere which do not exist on a new server?

Comment: delete everything inside caches(pdi_8.3\system\karaf\caches) folder and re-launch pdi..

Comment: Thx, I already tried this. I even removed the whole pdi-folder and unziped fresh from the downloaded archive, still the error persits

Comment: after deleting .kettle and .pentaho folder have you re-started your machine ? if not can you delete cache folder,.kettle,.pentaho folder re-start the machine and then try.

Comment: I didn't before. I tried now. Deleted everything under C:\pdi-ce-8.3.0.0-371\data-integration\system\karaf\caches. Deleted .pentaho, .swt unter my user (C:\USERS\). Deleted everything in .ketttle in my Home diretory except kettle.properties and repositories.xml. restarted the server. unfortunately this did not help.

Comment: can you remove kettle.properties and repositories.xml as well, i mean just rename it, let it generate fresh then you can copy paste the content.

Comment: unfortunately, this also didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue had been solved in not sharing the core pdi-files "C:\pdi-ce-8.3.0.0-371\data-integration" between differnt users. Server is now running since 2 weeks where each users has its own core files and so fare it is working fine.

Comment: Issue not solved, same problem started today again.

Answer (score 0):

Change the install folder, thats work for me !

Comment: thx for the comment. it has been a while an a year ago or so we reinstalled the terminal server and every user got his own pentaho in his own location since than the error did not show up again (fingers crossed).